AttributeError: partially initialized module 'whylogs' has no attribute 'package_version'
So I created a Dockerfile and currently using python 3.11-slim. When I try to run Dockerfile after building it, I run into this error. I am using langkit==0.0.33(and also tried using langkit[all]) but I still run into this attributeError. I'm not explicitly installing whylogs. It is a part of langkit. When I install requirements.txt and run this app on local machine, it runs absolutely fine
Error Shot
